# eclipse juno jstl error cannot find tag lib

Tags: eclipse, jstl, eclipse-juno

I have recently upgraded my Eclipse to Juno. Now when I open my Spring MVC project all my jsp files are marked with errors. The error is on this line

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

And the error message is:

```
    Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
```

I tried creating a fresh workspace and checking out my project from svn. This had no effect.

I have found that I can fix this by opening each file, making some trivial change and saving the file. Needless to say, this is not a very scalable fix.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can either Clean the project from the main menubar's Project menu and then Build All, or invoke the Validate action from the project's context menu.  Either will force the jsp files to be revalidated.

Comment: I would like to test your answer, nitind, but I don't have this problem any more. If I do run into the condition again I will test your solution.